# Using string.matches to check if last character is vowel

Tags: java, regex

I am new to matches in java. I want to determine if the last character of a string is a vowel (ie `aieou`). For example if the string is `abcde`, then it is ok. But if it is `eaoid`, then it is wrong.

Answer (score 11):

`str.matches(".*[aeiou]$");`

`.*` matches any character zero or more times
`[aeiou]` matches one of the characters in the set
`$` matches the end of the string.

So `"abcde".matches(".*[aeiou]$") == true` and `"eaoid".matches(".*[aeiou]$") == false`

Answer (score 5):

The `matches()` method in java must must the *whole* string in order to return `true`, so you need to start the regex with `.*` and finish it with a *character class* (square brackets around a list of characters), which is the regex way of saying "one of these characters"

If you want to match strings that end in either an upper or a lower case vowel:

```
str.matches(".*[AEIOUaeiou]");
```

or even more simply:

```
str.matches(".*(?i)[aeiou]");
```

The regex `(?i)` means "ignore case"