# Need help writing a clean code for an only vowels method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello I am fairly new to Ruby still learning. The goal for this code is to return a boolean given a string. This method should return true if all vowels are in the string, not in a certain order but only vowels should be in string. False otherwise. Ex: str("hello") => false. str("oii") => true. I have not made any progress other than what's below.

```
def only_vowels(str)
   vowels = "aeiou"
    str.all? #no idea what to use
end
```

Comment: "need help writing a clean code" - make it work first, _then_ worry about making it clean.

Comment: _"all vowels are in the string"_ and _"only vowels should be in string"_ are two different things.

Comment: @HazelAlvarez : Since you received good answers to your question, may I suggest that you accept one of them, or if they still don't answer your problem, explain what's missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.match?` method for a boolean result:

```
def only_vowels(str)
    str.match? /^[aeiou]+$/i
end
```

The `i` makes the regex case insensitive. (You could also use `(?i)` in the pattern for the same effect.)

Try it out:

```
> only_vowels("dfg")
false
> only_vowels("aei")
true
> only_vowels("Aei")
true
> only_vowels("")
false
```

---

Note:

'Only vowels' is dependent on **what is a vowel**? Do we include or exclude white space? Character returns? What about vowels including diacritics such as `à`? What about things that *sound* like a vowel such as `y` in `gym` or `my`?

There is a great Perl post on this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792789/298607).

Comment: `return` is spurious. There's also the `/.../i` form which is more commonly used.

Comment: `only_vowels("aei\nz") #=> true`. You need end-of-string, not end-of-line, anchors.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: fair point.  However, if a string has `\n` is it only vowels? You would need to add `\n` to to `"uooi\neea".delete('aeiou').empty?` for the same reason. (I like that method btw...)

Comment: @dawg : Interesting idea. The same would apply to a space, or characters such as `á` or `ä` or `あ`. Should we regard them as vowels? to me they are, but in general, the list of what exactly is a vowel, really should go only into the `[....]` part of the regexp, and not implicitly handled via the _end-of-line_ indicator of the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby's match method in a string for this:

```
def only_vowels(str)
   match = str.match(/[^aeiou]/)
   return match == nil
end
```

Notice that the call to `match` uses a regular expression that looks for anything that is not a vowel (`^aeiou`). If it finds nothing (`match == nil`) we can assume that there were only vowels.

You will need to add a check for an empty string since that will also return `match == nil`.

Comment: Even better: `str.match(...).nil?` or `!str.match?(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
"uooieea".delete('aeiou').empty?
  #=> true
```

```
"uoozieea".delete('aeiou').empty?
  #=> false
```

See [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your draft, using [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
str.chars.all? { |e| vowels.chars.include? e }
```

Of course, it is better to use a variable for the vowels array.